# Javascript get date and looping to combo box

Tags: javascript, jquery

For this case, I do not want to use a jQuery datetime picker. Because I make mobile apps.

[My case] I am using javascript to get the value of today's date and the next few days. But I want to be more flexible and want the data displayed on the dilooping and into the combo box using jquery.

To this day I get the data using :

```
function GetDay(){
     var today = new Date();
     var dd = today.getDate();
     var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
     var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
     if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
     alert(today);
}

Result : 2013-04-28
```

And for me the next day using :

```
function NextDay1(){
    var today = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} next1 = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
    alert(next1);
}

Result : 2013-04-29
```

The way that I use is very manual and if I want to get the data :

```
2013-04-28
2013-04-29
2013-04-30
2013-05-01
2013-05-02
ect...
```

The way that I use is very manual and if I want to get data like this and put on a combo box for the selection of that date?

Comment: The answer you accepted ain't gonna work. Check my answer for explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
var myDate = new Date();
var d = myDate.getFullYear() + '-' +  ('0' + (myDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' + myDate.getDate();
var myDates = [d]; //initialize array with today's date already in it.

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {        
    var fullDate = new Date(myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 1)); //add 1 not i
    var twoDigitMonth = ('0' + (fullDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var currentDate = fullDate.getFullYear() + "-" + twoDigitMonth + "-" + fullDate.getDate();
    myDates.push(currentDate);
}

console.log(myDates);
```

The problem with the answer you accepted is that adding `i` will change `myDate`, and since `i` keeps incrementing the `for` loop you add a different value to the date each time. And hence you get-

```
["2013-04-28", "2013-04-29", "2013-05-1", "2013-05-4", "2013-05-8"]
```

The date is incremented by a different value each time.

With my code you get-

```
["2013-04-28", "2013-04-29", "2013-04-30", "2013-05-1", "2013-05-2", "2013-05-3"]
```

Comment: We are getting this `["2013-31-29", "2013-31-30", "2013-41-1", "2013-41-2", "2013-41-3"] ` where not a single date is valid!

Comment: `2013-31-29` which month it is? `2013-41-2` This date is not in the calendar yet! Please have a look at the code again...

Comment: @PalashMondal My Bad... Forgot parenthesis. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the dates in loop like this:

```
// Create an empty array to store the dates generated
var myDates = [];

// Loop through for 5 times here
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var myDate = new Date();
    var fullDate = new Date(myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + i));
    var twoDigitMonth = ((fullDate.getMonth().length + 1) === 1) ? (fullDate.getMonth() + 1) : '0' + (fullDate.getMonth() + 1);
    var twoDigitDates = ('0' + fullDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var currentDate = fullDate.getFullYear() + "-" + twoDigitMonth + "-" + twoDigitDates;
    myDates.push(currentDate);
}

// Check the dates in console as an array
console.log(myDates);
```

Then insert into a drop-down like:

```
// Loop through the date array we have created
$.each(myDates, function (index, item) {

    // Add options to the select list
    $('#mySelect').append($('<option>', {
        value: index,
        text: item
    }));
});
```

Comment: @BerthoJoris: `var twoDigitDates = ('0' + fullDate.getDate()).slice(-2);`

Comment: It shouldn't be `new Date(myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + i))`, rather it should be - `new Date(myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 1))`. You have to add `1` not `i`. Your current code gives - `["2013-04-28", "2013-04-29", "2013-05-1", "2013-05-4", "2013-05-8"]`.

Comment: @Sann: If we add 1, we will get all the dates same as `["2013-04-29", "2013-04-29", "2013-04-29", "2013-04-29", "2013-04-29"]` and that's not the OP wants!

Comment: Well by my code, I meant the comment I added. I've posted an answer though.

Comment: Check my answer - it has to be `1`. The dates will get incremented by a different value every time across the loop.

Answer (score 2):

What we have here: a select and anonymous function to populate it. The `Date()` is outside the loop, so it is created only once. The padding is a separate function now. The number passed to the anonymous function is the total number of dates, including today. [FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mYuVH/2/).

HTML:

```
<form id="someform">
    <select id="year"></select>
</form>
```

JS:

```
//did you spot the mistake here ? :) 10 is not bigger than 10 and we end with 010
//function pad(v) { return v > 10 ? v : "0" + v; }

//the right way
function pad(v) { return v < 10 ? "0" + v : v; }
(function (max) {
    var counter = 0,
        d = new Date(),
        myselect = document.getElementById("year");
    do {
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
        myselect.add(
            new Option (
                d.getFullYear() + "-" +
                pad(d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" +
                pad(d.getDate()), 
                counter++),
            null
        );
    } while (counter < max);
})(5);
```

Comment: Hai @Bakudan ,  why this day result : 28, 29, 01, 04, 08 ?

Comment: I forgot, the counter in the setDate(). This way on every iteration it was adding a number of day to the old one, and when saving it, a progression appears. It is fixed now.